# What kind of descriptor should I use for seal cub detection?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection

I have a project to detect and count seal cubs (the animal) in an aerial image which is taken from beach. The seal cubs are black and small compared to adult seals which are brown and large.

Some seal cubs are overlapped/partly occluded. The beach color is near yellow however there're some black rocks that increase the detection difficulty.

What kind of descriptor is most suitable for my project? HOG, SIFT, Haar-like features?

I'm asking for the theory part of this problem. I think to implement my project, the first step should be choose correct descriptor that can most represent the object, then (combine several weak features, not necessary?) train a classifier using machine learning method like boosting/SVM/neural_network, am I right?

Sample image:
[image]

Comment: Supplement information: I'm asking for the theory part of this problem. I think to implement my project, the first step should be choose correct descriptor that can most represent the object, then (combine several weak features, not necessary?) train a classifier using machine learning method like boosting/SVM/neural_network, am I right?

Comment: Could you post an image sample?

Comment: Look for the men with clubs sneaking up on them.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I agree that selecting the right descriptor is the right place to start.  A fundamental issue is that all the objects are similar in shape.  There are also substantial gradients within each animal.  The complexity of poses is another issue.  I would break the problem into two more simple steps:
  1. Unique object detection (edge detection, watershed, [graph cut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_cuts_in_computer_vision) , etc).  Something like the "count blood cells" problem.
  2. Object classification based on color and area (normalized to camera perspective).  Compute the fractional amount of "yellow" colored pixels and "black" colored pixels in each object and use those values along with the object size as inputs to an object classifier (neural networks are a fun solution here!).

It is a fairly cluttered scene, so I would expect both of these algorithms to require some fine-tuning.  If your requirements allow some level of analyst interaction, provide some  sliders so the analyst can adjust each of the thresholds in your algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

Accuracy in computer vision algorithms seems to rely heavily on being able to fine tune them to a specific problem. If you can make assumptions about the pictures you are handing your algorithm, like the fact that all of them are aerial images of seals on a similar beach scene, then you can take advantage of that. I'd say before trying to get too fancy with local features, you might want to try something like watershed segmentation and count the number of non-background segments. Watershed provides a convenient framework called "markers" for incorporating prior knowledge about your input to differentiate between "background" and "foreground" segments.

An approach like this might be easier and possibly more accurate than local features. In my experience, I haven't been able to extract and match lots of meaningful features from organic subject matter (like faces or animals) using SIFT and SURF features. For me they have tended to work better on pictures of rooms or buildings with lots of angles.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure, you might try having a look at the predator algorithm, since you could teach it what a baby seal looks like with ease.
[youtube video, description and link here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1GhNXHCQGsM)

Comment: Thank you, that video is amazing! I'll google his paper behind this video

Comment: I don't think this is suitable at all. Eric is not trying to track the seals in a video, he is trying to detect and count them in images.

Comment: You could teach Predator what a particular baby seal looks like, then have it scan for variations on the theme, learning what other baby seals look like.
This way, there is less effort in teaching your algorithm what a baby seal would look like.
You could also teach it what an adult seal and rocks look like, so it can exclude them.